# Function is being called when page loads instead of on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I am trying to get this function to be called via click event, but for some reason it is being called when page loads. I am completely baffled on why my function is reacting this way.

Here is my function

```
var registerTab = function(panel){
    var active = 'off';
    if($('#'+panel).css('left') <= '0'){
        $('#'+panel).animate({left: '0'});
        active = 'on';
    } else {
        $('#'+panel).animate({left: '-380px'});
    } 
};

$(function() {
    tabRegister.on('click', registerTab('sidePanel'));
});
```

The weird thing is if i call it when i remove the passed variable and hard-code the selector in it works fine which again makes no since to me. Please any help would be very helpful and save me some hair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
registerTab('sidePanel')
```

This call will cause the function to be called immediately. I think what you really want is this:

```
tabRegister.on('click', function () { 
    registerTab('sidePanel')
});
```

Comment: haha thanks, i danced all around that solution. Works fine now thank you.

Comment: furthermore i wouldnt work with an "active" variable, i would do this via css class - which you can easily read and write with jquery

Comment: the 'active' was going to be used for a different idea but i never ended up implementing it. it actually has no use as of now and should be removed. thanks.